# Turbine Dashboard Metrics without Eureka

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix, netflix, turbine

I am working on two Spring-boot applications. I am using `spring-cloud-starter-hystrix` for circuit-breaking & fallback methods using `@EnableCircuitBreaker`.

Now I also want to have an `hystrix dashboard with metrics` which can be achieved by `Turbine Server` using `@EnableTurbine @EnableHystrixDashboard`.

AFAIK the Turbine service gets the application URLs from **`Eureka`** Instance. And in Turbine server app.properties we should give the other apps name. So that Turbine will check with Eureka on app url:port.

In my case, I am not using Eureka. So how can I use a Turbine Service to manually hardcode my application URL to fetch metric streams & display the metrics dashboard?

So basically in Turbine Server can I disable connection to Eureka & hardcode URLs to fetch metrics?

I have browsed for few hours & couldnt find a solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This may not suit your needs, but: you can configure your services and the turbine server to read/write to a kafka topic, instead of using http to communicate. I believe the topic name is springCloudHystrixStream. This removes the need for a discovery service like eureka, since all of the participating components are aware of the topic name.  This post has relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download and run turbine-web war file from [HERE](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.netflix.turbine) and deploy it on any server say a tomcat with a JVM runtime argument specifying the location of your turbine config file. Something like-

> -Darchaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls=file:///etc/files/turbine-archaius.properties"

2. Add configuration like your server IPs, URI of hystrix stream servlet in that file. Take more help from [HERE](https://github.com/Netflix/Turbine/wiki/Configuration-(1.x)).

Here's my sample config file for better understanding-

> turbine.aggregator.clusterConfig=<cluster-name>
>
> turbine.instanceUrlSuffix.<cluster-name>=/hystrix.stream
>
> #I am using a separate file to list down all my server IPs that turbine need to agregate data from
>   turbine.FileBasedInstanceDiscovery.filePath=/etc/files/turbine-server-list
>
> InstanceDiscovery.impl=com.netflix.turbine.discovery.FileBasedInstanceDiscovery
>
> turbine.InstanceMonitor.eventStream.skipLineLogic.enabled=false

The other file turbine-server-list contains server IPs from which to aggregate metrics. something like-

> APPLICATION-IP1:PORT,<cluster-name>,up
>
> APPLICATION-IP2:PORT,<cluster-name>,up

3. Find your aggregated turbine metrics at- http://TURBINE-SERVER-IP:PORT/turbine/turbine.stream?cluster=cluster-name

Comment: Hey, I was not able to get this to work.  Turbine always uses Eureka, it ignores the InstanceDiscovery.impl.  this is when I am building my own spring-boot app

Comment: @devo Spring boot does things a bit differently. I haven't exactly integrated this with spring boot. This works well with spring MVC projects. Are you using spring-cloud-starter-turbine maven dependency?

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back.  You are right, the spring-boot way is very different than the way you document above.  I was able to figure it out.  Asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56136876/problems-with-hystrix-dashboard-turbine-using-filebasedinstancediscovery