# Problems with hystrix-dashboard turbine using FileBasedInstanceDiscovery

Tags: hystrix, turbine

I am trying to set up a hystrix-dashboard with turbine.  I am not using Eureka and want to use the FileBasedInstanceDiscovery.  I am trying to configure this but following the online documentation doesn't seem to work.  It always tries to use the Eureka discovery client.  I tried excluding the eureka from my pom but then it falls back to another discovery client CommonsInstanceDiscovery

Here is my application.properties:

```
turbine.aggregator.clusterConf=mycluster
turbine.instanceUrlSuffix.mycluster=8080/hystrix.stream
turbine.FileBasedInstanceDiscovery.filePath=turbine.hostnames.txt
turbine.InstanceMonitor.eventStream.skipLineLogic.enabled=false
InstanceDiscovery.impl=com.netflix.turbine.discovery.FileBasedInstanceDiscovery
```

Is there another way to do this?  Also, for the filePath for my turbine hostnames, where does it start looking?  Can I have the file under my resources directory of my jar?

here is my pom file dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-turbine</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the documentation is unclear and conflicting for turbine, I think this is because there is the spring-cloud-netflix project and a standalone turbine project.  At any rate, if you are building a spring-boot app then this property is not useful:

```
InstanceDiscovery.impl=com.netflix.turbine.discovery.FileBasedInstanceDiscovery
```

If you want to change the implementation of InstanceDiscovery it is pretty simple, just create a bean that implements InstanceDiscovery like this:

```
@Bean
public InstanceDiscovery instanceDiscovery() {
    //choose either one of the provided implementations from spring or
    //create your own
    return new ConfigPropertyBasedDiscovery();
    //return new FileBasedInstanceDiscovery();
}
```

Make sure you put this in a @Configuration class.  I originally had mine just in my SpringBootApplication class but this doesn't allow you to override the default implementation.